# How do I grant Read/Write Permissions to internal storage of my application to TextToSpeech/MediaPlayer?

Tags: android, media-player, text-to-speech, synthesis

How do I grant Read/Write Permissions to internal storage of my application to TextToSpeech/MediaPlayer?

TextToSpeech.synthesizeToFile return -1 when I attempt to store file in internal storage of application ( for folder like /data/data/my.mycode.mydata/ )

It works for SD card when I give permission for it. I think I get error ( return value -1 ) since TextToSpeech/MediaPlayer does not have permission for internal storage file creation.

How do I provide it? probabally through manifest.xml?

Answer (score 2):

You have two options.

The better approach is to create a `ContentProvider` that will serve your files, and use the associated `content://` `Uri` values when working with "TextToSpeech/MediaPlayer". [Here is a sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/ContentProvider/Files) demonstrating an app serving up a PDF file, copied out of the project's assets, to be viewed by a PDF viewer on the device.

Alternatively, create the file using [`openFileOutput()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#openFileOutput%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) and `MODE_WORLD_READABLE`.